# WebRequest instantly throws 'Unable to connect to remote server'

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using a `WebRequest` with the code:

```
bool error = false;
WebException exc = null;
statusText.Text = "Starting";
String urlRequest = "http://****PRIVATER URL****/CC/runCode.php?lang=";
urlRequest += global.language;
urlRequest += "&code=";
urlRequest += Uri.EscapeDataString(global.codeString);
statusText.Text = "Requesting";
webRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlRequest);
webRequest.Proxy = null;
//webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(webRequestDone), null);

try
{
    using (resp =  await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        //TODO get this working!
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    error = true;
    exc = e;
}
if (error)
{
    await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(exc.Message).ShowAsync();
}
```

The web server is accessible, without the use of a proxy. If I get the response outside of a `try catch` clause, it runs just fine, like below:

```
bool error = false;
                WebException exc = null;
                statusText.Text = "Starting";
                String urlRequest = "http://****PRIVATE URL****/CC/runCode.php?lang=";
                urlRequest += global.language;
                urlRequest += "&code=";
                urlRequest += Uri.EscapeDataString(global.codeString);
                statusText.Text = "Requesting";
                webRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlRequest);
                webRequest.Proxy = null;
                //webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(webRequestDone), null);
                resp = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to answer this question. There are lots of reasons why connecting to the remote server could be failing, whether it's your firewall, any proxies you're behind, or most likely, whether your server or any network devices it's behind are refusing the connection.

Comment: I can access the server just fine if I remove the `try catch`. Is there something wrong with the `try catch`?

Comment: You're still calling `GetResponseAsync` when removing the `try/catch`? No, it doesn't make sense that the `try/catch` would change the behavior.

Comment: @Jacob I updated my question. The second block of code runs just fine without any errors, but I can't catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. Turns out I didn't have access to private networks. So it always failed when I was on my local network. I had to add it under Capabilities in app.appxmanifest.